# Unexpected recursion for the A193231 (blue code of $n$)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A193231](https://oeis.org/A193231), blue code of $n$ i.e. self-inverse permutation of non-negative integers such that $a(n)<2^k$ iff $n<2^k$ and
  $$
  a(n\operatorname{XOR}k) = a(n) \operatorname{XOR} a(k)
  $$
- Let
  $$
  b_1(n) = n \operatorname{XOR} 2n, \\
  b_2(n) = n \operatorname{XOR} (2n+1)
  $$
  Then we have
  $$
  a(2n) = b_1(a(n)), \\
  a(2n+1) = b_2(a(n)), \\
  a(0) = 0, \\
  a(1) = 1
  $$
- Let
  $$
  \ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor
  $$
- Let
  $$
  f(n) = 2^{\ell(n)}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  g(n) = 2(a(f(n) - 1)\operatorname{XOR}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor) + 1 - n\operatorname{mod}2 + f(n)
  $$

I conjecture that for $n>1$
$$a(n) = a(g(n) - f(n)) + f(n) = g(a(n - f(n)) + f(n)).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a(n) = {local(x='x); subst(lift(Mod(1, 2)*subst(Pol(binary(n), x), x, 1+x)), x, 2)};
upto1(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, i == 2); for(i=2, n, my(A = 2^logint(i, 2)); v1[i + 1] = v1[2 * bitxor(v1[A], i \ 2) + 2 - i % 2] + A); v1
upto2(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n + 1, i, i == 2); for(i=2, n, my(A = 2^logint(i, 2), B = v1[i - A + 1] + A); v1[i + 1] = 2 * bitxor(v1[A], B \ 2) + 1 - B % 2 + A); v1
test1(n) = vector(n + 1, i, a(i - 1)) == upto1(n)
test2(n) = vector(n + 1, i, a(i - 1)) == upto2(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?